# Existing tcp forward proxy like squid?

Tags: tcp, proxy, forward

As far as i know, squid can be as proxy forward proxy. for example

```
docker run -d -p 3128:3128 --name squid0 wernight/squid
curl --proxy http://localhost:3128/ example.com
```

Above example is for `http`, i have used google to search, didn't find any `tcp forward proxy` software can implement above similar function.

Existing any tcp forward proxy can implement similar function?